# How do I handle back key event from User Home Activity in my app?

Tags: android, android-fragments

As of now if I press back key, it navigates to Login Fragment with no view(blank white screen erasing the email id, password and submit button controls).

Following is the code in 'UserHomeActivity' class

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.user_drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
    else {
       // perform_exit_logout();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

}
```

Comment: you might be having different fragments in the stack, can you post your complete code, or you could just mention your lifecycle, what and where you're adding components

Answer (score 0):

if you want to exit the application use the following codes

```
             Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
```